# Creating a function that prints your Age in years when you input your DOB using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After a hundred tries i finally got it to work, but i was wondering if there is another way to write this code, I'm kinda a rookie in python, i would appreciate any assistance.

```
import datetime

date= datetime.datetime.now()
def age_calc(age):
    age = date.year - int(dob)
    return age
dob=input("Please Enter DOB here: ")

print("You are %s years old" % age_calc(dob))
```

Comment: There's not too many other ways to write an input prompt and subtraction and print statement... What are you expecting exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Even for a small program like this, there are always things to improve and learn. Some suggestions:

- Be explicit in names of variables and correct! You have age as argument for `age_calc`,  but this is actually the date_of_birth. Everyone knows what is `dob` though it is still better to spell it out especially if it is out of context.
- The calculation is incorrect, I am born 5-Nov-1983 and thus still 35 years old, not 36 years as your program tells me
- You are asking for DOB, but in fact you request the year of birth, always good to make clear what format you need
- It is good practice to do some error checking of the manual input
- Make use of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` construct and split the program in several functions that do each one thing.
- I personally love the use of f-strings `f"Hello {name}"`

Have a look a the refactored code below to make the point.

```
import datetime

def age_calc(date_of_birth):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    age_days = current_date - date_of_birth
    age_years = int(age_days.days / 365.25)
    return age_years

def get_date_of_birth():
    answered = False
    while not answered:
        dob_answer = input("Please Enter DOB here (DD-MM-YYYY) (enter q to quit): ")

        if dob_answer in ['q', 'Q']:
            exit()

        try:
            date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(dob_answer, "%d-%m-%Y")
            answered = True

        except ValueError:
            print(f"{dob_answer} has incorrect format, use: d-m-yyyy")

    return date_of_birth

def print_age(date_of_birth):
    print(f"You are {age_calc(date_of_birth)} years old")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        dob = get_date_of_birth()
        print_age(dob)
```

Good luck!